# Splash page for CRM 2011 Outlook client

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We have CRM Dynamics 2011 setup with Outlook as a client.  We need to show some sort of Splash page or user friendly message to outlook client when CRM server is not available ( maybe in Maintenance mode / release is going on etc.)

How can we achieve that?  IF it is web, it would have been easier, but how to achieve that in outlook client.

We cannot take outlook to offline mode as offline mode is not permitted in organization.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We are still running Dynamics CRM 4.0.  By using the "A redirection to a URL" option on the properties of the root site and pointing to a custom but simple HTML page I was able to display my own splash page both in the IE Client and in the Outlook Client.